# Git rebase of unrelated histories

Tags: git

I am trying to do a rebase with two unrelated branches in Git.

```
| A A A A A |       =>      | A A A A A B B |
    | B B |
```

However, in doing so, all I am left with is just the commits from branch `M`.
Demonstration:

```
$ git init && git ci -m "MASTER branch" --allow-empty
[master (root-commit) 05abfe5] MASTER branch
$ git co --orphan FEATURE && git ci -m "FEATURE branch" --allow-empty
Switched to a new branch 'FEATURE'
[FEATURE (root-commit) 122671d] FEATURE branch
$ git rebase master
First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...
$ git lg
* 05abfe5 - (HEAD -> FEATURE, master) MASTER branch (18 seconds ago) <Niklas Rosenstein>
```

What I would expect from the last command is

```
$ git lg
* 122671d - (HEAD -> FEATURE) FEATURE branch (1 second ago) <Niklas Rosenstein>
* 05abfe5 - (master) MASTER branch (18 seconds ago) <Niklas Rosenstein>
```

---

1. Is that expected behaviour – and if so, why? I would have expected a "can not rebase unrelated histories" error much like with `git merge` instead of this behaviour.
2. How can I fix the `git rebase` command to perform the rebase as described above?

Comment: Use `git rebase master --keep-empty` instead or creates some commits with real changes.

Comment: Oh -- so it's not actually an issue with the rebase but with empty commits

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As ElpieKay noted in a comment, you need `--keep-empty` for this particular example.  Git in general has a tendency to throw out, or not make in the first place, commits that make no change to the tree.  There's no reason it *has* to do that—two commits in a row that use the same tree is a normal case; it occurs with `git merge -s ours` for instance—but it does.

When using `git rebase` in its non-interactive, non-cherry-picking modes, Git uses `git format-patch` to turn each commit into a patch, and `git am` (apply mailbox-formatted patches) to re-apply them, to make the copies of the original commits.  The format-patch command is unable to format a "do nothing" patch, so when you use `-k` or `--keep-empty`, Git switches to using `git cherry-pick` to copy the commits.

There are other options that force rebase to use cherry-pick, such as `--interactive` and `--merge`.  Cherry-picking *also* defaults to omitting "empty" commits and also requires `--keep-empty`, whether invoked directly, or from this other kind of rebase.

Comment: I just did a rebase of unrelated histories with an empty root and it didn't work. Had to `-i` and remove the initial `t [new root]` and first `pick` to achieve what I wanted